# Android bundled notifications behaviour

Tags: android, android-notifications

Android N introduced **Bundled notifications**:

> posting 4 or more notifications without a group will cause those
>   notifications to be automatically bundled.

I'm creating four very similar notifications with different tag and id but with the same icon. After notifying `NotificationManagerCompat` and creating 4rd notification, all notifications are bundled into one with my application name and grey icon. And this leads to strange behaviour because it looks like that icon is **greyed out shape of my applications launcher icon** instead of `smallIcon` from `NotificationCompat.Builder`

I created sample app and tried to simulate the same environment, and created 4 notifications using same builder methods as in first application. Instead grey shape, I can see original `smallIcon` from builder which is correct behaviour.

On the screen, first notification is from my **sample app**, the second one is from my **main app**.

Creating notifications in both apps looks the same:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert_octagon_white)
                    .setContentTitle("contentTitle 2")
                    .setTicker("ticker 2")
                    .setContentText("contentText 2")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("bigText 2"));
NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify("tag2", 2, notifBuilder.build());
```

Where can I look for the differences? How can I set bundled notification icon?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the difference in behavior you are seeing but i think something in Android Nougat default Notification bundling is screwed up.

To avoid that specifically call `setGroup()` and `setGroupSummary()` on your Builder object.That would solve the issue.